# Echoing arrays generated via CSV

Tags: php, arrays, csv

First of all, please note I am still learning so I apologise for the basic questions...

I am importing a CSV file of water storage levels which is generated via other systems, the CSV looks like:

```
#TYPE System.Data.DataRow
"storageid","storagedesc","storagecap","storagelvl","storagelvlprevwk","storagelvlml","readingdate"
"Moondarra","Moondarra","29700","101","101.2","30007.2   ","3/09/2015 12:00:00 AM"
"BlueRock","Blue Rock (SRW)","208190","100","100","208197    ","3/09/2015 12:00:00 AM"
"GMAGGIE","Glenmaggie (SRW)","177640","96.5","96.9","171446    ","3/09/2015 12:00:00 AM"
"TARAGO","Tarago (Melb Water)","36580","101.2","0","38038     ","3/09/2015 12:00:00 AM"
```

I have managed to import the CSV successfully with:

```
$file = fopen('http://www.dev.development/data/csv/StorageLvls.csv', 'r');
while (($storage = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  //$line is an array of the csv elements
  print_r($storage);
}
fclose($file);
```

Which generates the following array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => storageid 
    [1] => storagedesc 
    [2] => storagecap 
    [3] => storagelvl 
    [4] => storagelvlprevwk 
    [5] => storagelvlml 
    [6] => readingdate 
    ) 
Array ( 
    [0] => Moondarra 
    [1] => Moondarra 
    [2] => 29700 
    [3] => 101 
    [4] => 101.2 
    [5] => 30007.2 
    [6] => 3/09/2015 12:00:00 AM 
    ) 
Array ( 
    [0] => BlueRock 
    [1] => Blue Rock (SRW) 
    [2] => 208190 
    [3] => 100 [4] => 100 
    [5] => 208197 
    [6] => 3/09/2015 12:00:00 AM 
    ) 
Array ( 
    [0] => GMAGGIE 
    [1] => Glenmaggie (SRW) 
    [2] => 177640 
    [3] => 96.5 
    [4] => 96.9 
    [5] => 171446 
    [6] => 3/09/2015 12:00:00 AM 
    ) 
Array ( 
    [0] => TARAGO 
    [1] => Tarago (Melb Water) 
    [2] => 36580 
    [3] => 101.2 
    [4] => 0 
    [5] => 38038 
    [6] => 3/09/2015 12:00:00 AM 
)
```

Where I'm struggling is what to do next...

I am firstly trying to echo only the last four rows (being the latest).

I also need to strip out the first column.

I also need to be able to target each column in a foreach statement in order to graph certain columns.

I have tried a few different ways of echoing the data but I only seem to get myself more confused... I am wondering if there is something wrong with the way my array is generated or more likely, my own lack of understanding.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: its just a 2d array at this point so should be easy: `$storage[$x][$y]` etc.

Comment: Rearrange your array first.